# Webinstaller for C# application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, installation

I have created a console installer which does the following things

- Downloads zip files from server and extracts it on user system
- Copies a folder from the extracted files in maya install directory after searching for its install path from registry
- Adds registry entry for another exe file my application is using
- Downloads and places that exe from server on user system

Its working perfectly fine but its not user friendly as the user keeps looking at console while app downloads and extracts data on his system.

I looked and found few auto setup installers.
Is clickonce use able for my scenario or should i go for some other or should i create my own gui for the app and add progress bar.

P.S: I am using c#, .net framework 4.5

Comment: If you want it to look like and do exactly what you want, build your own. If you want it fast and simple use an auto setup installer

Comment: @g3mini is it possible to achieve what I listed above with an auto setup installer? If so, can you guide me how or with some useful links please

Comment: It would probably be possible, any reason why you don't just zip it in an auto extractor?